# (HSQLDB)EclipseにJDBドライバのクラスパスを通す方法

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

「基礎からのサーブレット」という本でEclipseを使ってサーブレットの勉強をしています。

EclipseにJDBドライバのクラスパスを通すために、
①hsqldb>libにあるhsqldb.jarをmyproject>WEB-INF>libにコピー
②Eclipseにて、プロジェクト>プロパティ>Javaのビルド・パス>ライブラリー>JARの追加から
hsqldb.jarを追加しました。

Javaのビルドパスにはhsqldbのアイコンも表示されているのですが、
main関数を持つJavaファイルでデータベースとの接続を試みると、
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbsDriver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbsDriver
というエラーが発生します。

Classが見つからないということはビルドパスが通っていないのでしょうか？？
原因がわかるか方いましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

すみません。ソースコードが間違っているだけでした